# How do you launch a Chrome extension without going to the app store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

A few months ago there was an update to Google Chrome that got rid of all my "Apps" on the home page. There's only one I use, and now that it's gone it's incredibly frustrating.

I use the [PostMan App](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm/related?hl=en) to test REST interfaces, and the only way I can find to launch the app is to visit the Chrome App Store first and launch it from there.

The extension is installed (in settings > extensions) -- and it doesn't come up in the omnibar when I type "PostMan" either.

How do I fix this so I can launch the app without searching for it first??

[image]

Comment: Are you appropriately logged into your Google account since the Chrome update?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This update was a bit annoying. You can see it at chrome://apps/. For a quicker way to access it, you can:

- install the [Chrome App Launcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/launcher), then
- add a shortcut on your taskbar.

You can now easily open the app.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I'm just going to make `chrome://apps/` my home page haha

Comment: It's incredible that the installed addons don't even show up on the list of your apps. What a crock.

Comment: Official Chrome app launcher now going teh way of the dodo, but the chrome://apps/ still works - http://www.theverge.com/2016/3/22/11287450/chrome-app-launcher-being-removed-google

Comment: Those are applications, not extensions.

Comment: Is this solution still valid after the 2020-2022 App-ocolypse? https://blog.chromium.org/2020/08/changes-to-chrome-app-support-timeline.html

chrome://apps/ is not valid on my chromebook, version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 12):

As described in help page on how to [Use the New Tab page](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2918032?hl=en), you can click the "Apps" button in the top left corner of the new tab page (#3 below).

[image: New Tab Page]

Comment: Mine doesn't have that bar, and the thing representing "apps" on the home page doesn't have any apps that aren't made by Google. Thanks though!

Comment: Sometimes we are lazy enough and stackoverflow comes to rescue...

Comment: No such button or bar option, probably because Chome Apps are dead 2020-2022.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't see the "Apps" shortcut in the upper left corner on the new tab page, right click on the bar/area below the url/search box and check "Show apps shortcut"

(sorry, i didn't have enough cred to post a screenshot)

Comment: I cannot right click on the little gray lining below url bar. So have to show bookmark bar and then only able to right click.

Comment: No more chrome apps, chrome finished killing them off 2020-2022.

Answer (score 5):

You can now go in to chrome://apps/ and right click the app. There you can create a short to the desktop

Comment: Those are applications, not extensions.

Answer (score 2):

On UI in Google Chrome `Version 79.0.3945.130` in bookmark bar
[image: enable showing of apps shortcut]
[image: apps icon]

Comment: No such option, version 103.0.5060.114 (Official Build) (64-bit)